# C++ custom array container dynamic size

Tags: c++, arrays, containers

For a school assignment I want to build a custom array container as I'm not allowed to use containers provided by std, or any library available, while self made is allowed.

So far everything I have is working but I want to double my array size as soon as I reach the limit. how can i do this, all i can find is using vector (which i'm not allowed).

```
#ifndef UTILS_ARRAY_HEADER_INCLUDED
#define UTILS_ARRAY_HEADER_INCLUDED

#include <array>

namespace utils
{
    template <class T>
    struct Array
    {

    private:
        int count = 0;
        int size = 1;

        std::array<T, 1> myArray;
        void doubleSize();
    public:
        T* begin();
        T* end();
        T& operator[] (int);
        void addItem(T const);
    };

    template <class T>
    T* Array<T>::begin()
    {
        return &myArray[0];
    }

    template <class T>
    T* Array<T>::end()
    {
        if (&myArray[count])
            return &myArray[count];
        return &myArray[0];
    }

    template <class T>
    T& Array<T>::operator[] (int key)
    {
        return myArray[key];
    }

    template <class T>
    void Array<T>::addItem(T const item)
    {
        if (count >= 0 && count < size)
        {
            myArray[count] = item;
            count++;
        }
        else {
            doubleSize();
        }

        return;
    }

    template <class T>
    void Array<T>::doubleSize()
    {
        // ?
        /*size = size * 2; 
        const int newsize = 2;
        std::array<T, newsize> newArray; // not working.
        std::copy(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), std::begin(newArray));
        myArray = newArray;*/
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: If you want to be able to resize your container you can't be using std::array as an internal data holder.

Comment: Since it's your homework, the maximum hint I can give you is pointers.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use anything from `std::` then why are you using `std::array<T, 1> myArray;`?  Just look up how to implement vector in C++ and you will find results like [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60484/stl-vector-implementation) that will give you a example you can reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver The assignment has two rules, no libraries or containers. but everything that is not a container from std is still allowed to be use. and arrays are considered allowed aswell as self made containers.

Comment: OK.  Your not going to want to use a `std::array` though since it's size must be known at compile time which is opposite of what you need.

Comment: BTW: `if (&myArray[count])` - that is problematic. The compiler may very well optimize that to `if (true)` - there's no reasonable scenario in which it can be `false`.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you suggest for an alternative?
@ MSalters I know, Im working on that, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Multi-Cab See my first comment.  It has a link to a sister site that shows how you could implement what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You need properties:

- current capacity: int
- current size (max used index): int
- pointer to your data: T *

In AddItem check if current_size < current_capacity. If yes,
create new_data with size of currernt_capacity * 2, copy each item, delete old data and replace pointer.

Remember to do delete data; in destructor. I won't give you more code, it's your homework.

Checkout [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to check if your code does not leak memory.

Comment: Not sure what you're are saying. my code has the int size and int count. where size is it max size at that moment and count the current element count.
Also since i'm running it within VS studio and use _CRTDBG to check for memory leak, no issue so far unless it crases but that is work in process.

Comment: change std::Array<T,1> myArray to T * and make it work. That's all :)

Comment: The reason i use std::array<> instead of a pointer is because i have no clue how to add, or get an element from it, so make it work is not that easy.

Comment: @Multi-Cab: Indeed it's not easy, that's why this is an exercise. But first consider the easy case: what if the current size is less than the capacity? And then the next problem: what if the capacity is too small?

Comment: then you run your function double_size which would create temporary pointer `T* new_data = new T[current_capacity*2]`, copy old data from myArray, DELETE (THIS IS IMPORTANT!) myArray, and then do `myArray = new_data;`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `std::array<T, 1>` is not allowed either. But that's not a real problem: you can't use `array` anyway since it has a fixed size.

You'll need to store a `T* begin`, a `size_t current_size` and a `size_t size_in_use`.

Comment: So far no issue, the 1 is currently just for testing will be increased later.
I know it fixed size that why i want to dynamicly allocate it. It should be possible to overwrite myArray with a newArray right?

Comment: @Multi-Cab: You can change the number in an `std::array<int,1>` but you can't change the fact that `std::array<int,1>` holds exactly one integer. In C++, types do not change. That is to say, `addItem`  cannot turn `std::array<int,1>` into an `std::array<int,2>`

Comment: that's why there is type of just std::array<T> which can hold more and more items. You can achieve the same with 'T * myArray = new int[current_capacity];'.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek: [There is?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Allright, it is called std::vector, but does exactly that. Still, the goal is to do this without using std structures/classes, but with pointers